# PHP: JSON decoding problem

Tags: php, json

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sinanoezcan@hotmail.com&type=user&access_token=2227472222|2.mLWDqcUsekDYK_FQQXYnHw__.3600.1279803900-100001310000000|YxS1eGhjx2rpNYzzzzzzzLrfb5hMc.", "rb");
$json = stream_get_contents($handle);
fclose($handle);
echo $json;
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->{'id'};
?>
```

Here is the JSON: `{"data":[{"name":"Sinan \u00d6zcan","id":"610914868"}]}`

It echos the JSON but I was unable to print the id.

Also I tried:

```
<?php
$obj = json_decode($json);
$obj = $obj->{'data'};
print $obj->{'id'};
?>
```

Comment: a) Instead of fopen/stream_get_contents/fclose, why not use `$json = file_get_contents($url);`? b) Have a look at `var_dump($obj)`, maybe it'll help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` is an array, so it should be:

```
print $obj[0]->{'id'};
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that there is an array in the JSON.

```
{
    "data": [   // <--
      {
        "name": "Sinan \u00d6zcan",
        "id":   "610914868"
      }
    ]           // <--
}
```

You could try `$obj = $obj->{'data'}[0]` to get the first element in that array.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the key `"data"` is an array of objects, so this should work:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->data[0]->name;
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Have you tried `$obj->data` or `$obj->id`?</strike>

**Update:** Others have noted that it should be `$obj->data[0]->id` and so on.

PS You may not want to include your private Facebook access tokens on a public website like SO...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit more complicated than that, when you get an associative array out of it:

```
$json = json_decode('{"data":[{"name":"Sinan \u00d6zcan","id":"610914868"}]}', true);
```

Then you may echo the id with:

```
var_dump($json['data'][0]['id']);
```

Without assoc, it has to be:

```
var_dump($json->data[0]->id);
```